# preview thumbnail for .agr (Grace)files 12.04

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

In Ubuntu 12.04 Nautilus is not showing preview thumbnails for `.agr` files produced by [Grace](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grace/) unlike Ubuntu 10.04. How can I have preview thumbnails for `.agr` files on Ubuntu 12.04.

sample file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfb0z8xfg7p4nvq/sample.agr

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and install `xfig-libs`  with `sudo apt-get install xfig-libs`

then try again.

Comment: `xfig-libs` is already the newest version

Comment: a picture/icon thumbnail is always there but I wish to have preview thumbnail like 10.04/10.10.

Comment: @souravc I will give you some way , but be careful. download the 10.04 xfig-libs and install it. may be the integration is the problem. another way is trying out some other filemanageres.

Comment: tried with `dolphin` but result is the same.

Comment: @souravc then go with old version of xfig-libs..

Comment: I installed `xfig-libs_3.2.5.b-1ubuntu1_all.deb` but could not see any change.